# How to synchronize between threads out of which one is a timer using pthread?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex, semaphore

I want to make a process with 3 threads. Out of which, I want one thread to work once in every 50ms. So made 2 threads to do my other works and in the third thread I initialised a timer. When I did so the synchronisation between the threads doest seem that good. I cant find the timer codes executing in every 50ms. Its random in nature. The code brief is shown below. Thanks in advance.

```
void * vUserInterfaceThread()
{
    while(1)
    {
        //***doing my interface code here***********/
    }
}
void * vMornitorThread()
{
    while(1)
    {
        //***doing my monitor code here***********/
    }
}
void * vTimerThread()
{
    vStartTimer(ENABLE); // enabled the timer with 50ms delay with the function 
     while(1);
}
void vTimerFunction()
{
    //******Code to be executed in every  50ms time duration here************//
}
void vStartTimer(unsigned char ucValue)
{
    if(ucValue == ENABLE)
    {
        memset (&sSigActionStruct, 0, sizeof (sSigActionStruct));
        sSigActionStruct.sa_handler = &vTimerHandler;
        sigaction (SIGVTALRM, &sSigActionStruct, NULL);

        iTimerValue.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
        iTimerValue.it_value.tv_usec = TIMERLOADVALUE; //Load value for 50ms

        iTimerValue.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
        iTimerValue.it_interval.tv_usec = TIMERLOADVALUE; //Load value for 50ms
        setitimer (ITIMER_VIRTUAL/*ITIMER_REAL*/, &iTimerValue, NULL);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    //***************doing other initialisations***************************//
        pthread_create(&pThreadID1,NULL,vUserInterfaceThread,NULL);
        pthread_create(&pThreadID2,NULL,vMornitorThread,NULL);
        pthread_create(&pThreadID3,NULL,vTimerThread,NULL);
        pthread_join(pThreadID1,NULL);
        pthread_join(pThreadID2,NULL);
        pthread_join(pThreadID3,NULL);
}
```

Comment: What synchronization do you need? I've read your question and looked at your code and I still can't figure out what you're asking.

Comment: Add more description to your question. What exactly you want?

Comment: What kind of timer are you using?  I suspect that `while(1);` may not be a good idea... if vTimerThread() is just enabling a timer that will execute a callback function, you might not need that thread at all...

Comment: I am doing an embedded application. I tried to find out the exact time interval at which the timer is working with the help of a GPIO pin being toggled at each timer routine. I was not able to see the pin toggling in exact 50ms delay. The toggling was random. Sometimes the Pin goes high for more than 100ms and low for less than 50ms and vice versa. What I want to achieve is the the pins should toggle in exact 50ms delay. To be more specific the timer I would like the timer to work with a higher priority than other threads.

Comment: I use the timer handler as the signal handler for SIGVTALRM.

Comment: I have updated the vStartTimer funtion in the question.

Comment: I tried to execute the timer without a thread. What happened was that the same. The toggling was so random. May be the timer is having less priority. I am working in Linux environment for ARM Architecture. I want the timer to be off highest priority than any other thread. When the timer starts servicing, I want all other thread to be in sleep state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer a part of your question:

If you want to adjust your thread priorities you can use `pthread_attr_setschedparam`

```
pthread_attr_t thread_attributes;
pthread_attr_init(&thread_attributes);
struct sched_param params = {.sched_priority = 15}; // Set higher/lower priorities in other threads
pthread_attr_setschedparam(&thread_attributes, &params);
pthread_create(&pThreadID1, &thread_attributes, vUserInterfaceThread, NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks mate. It Worked. I made higher priority for the timer thread. Then it seemed to be working fine. I could see the GPIO toggling at exact 50ms along with other threads running in parallel.